# How do i open the RDP port in Linux?

Tags: linux, port, rdp

**Prologue**
I have a MacBook and i want to connect to a remote Windows machine, which is connected to a Linux Server.
When i'm at my locally there in the network, i use the http://www.microsoft.com/mac/remote-desktop-client to connect to the windows machine.

Now i want to do the same from home. The Windows machine is not connected to the internet.

**Question**
The magic word is ssh Tunnel. So far so good. But i'm not quite able to manage it.
I think the problem is with the port on the linux machine.
**How do i open the RDP port on the Server ?** ( given the permissions )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your Mac, you will need to open an SSH tunnel. This assumes that you have SSH access to the Linux server at work and a valid user account on that Linux server.

In a Terminal.app window on your Mac, something like:

`sudo ssh -L 3389:windows_internal_IP:3389 username@linux_external_IP`

Where `windows_internal_IP` is the internal IP that you use to access the Windows system at work and `linux_external_IP` is the internet-facing IP address of the Linux server. `username` is your user name on the Linux system.

If that connection is successful, you'll be able open your Mac's Remote Desktop client and connect to `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Good. The `sudo` is specifically needed on the Mac. Please mark the answer here as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
ssh -L 3389:YourWinPCIPaddr:3389 username@server.IP.ad.dress
```

This will forward WinPCs RDP (port 3389 i think) to your local pc's port 3389.

Then just use the RDP client to connect to 'localhost'

ps, if you're running RDP on your local machine too, it will not let you bind to 3389. Then you have to choose another port:

```
ssh -L 12345:YourWinPCIPaddr:3389 username@server.IP.ad.dress
```

And then connect to localhost:12345

Comment: Thanks. I would also vote you up. But i need 15 Reputation :(

Comment: @fragant1996 Now that you've got a few upvotes on your question, you now have enough rep.